# Where do we have to put a linux command?

Tags: linux, bash, command, location

I just coded a script in bash on Ubuntu but I don't know where I should put it...

I read I had to put it in /usr/bin in a tutorial but maybe it's better directly in /bin ?

Comment: Cross-site question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201768/storing-shell-scripts.

Answer (score 1):

This is the difference between both directories:

**/bin**

It contains commands that can be used by both the system administrator and the users, but which are necessary when other file systems are not mounted (for example, in single user mode). It can also contain commands that scripts use indirectly

**/usr/bin/**

This is the main directory of executable commands in the system.

Therefore, it will work on both, but you must establish what responsibility your script has.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I think my problem is I don't manage to distinguish how the roles of these two directories are different... It's like both contains the main command of the system.